# unexpected end of input php jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, input

I have written same code at one machine and it is working fine but on other machine same code is giving error unexpected end of input. This is driving me crazy as why it is happening. Anybody who can help, please. These are my files with which I am working.

edit: I am making a small online test application for learning purpose. As the test start, the first question appears, on clicking next button the url changes to what it should be but next question does not appear and the error in the console says unexpected end of input. Since all my brackets are ok, I am not able to find error. Please help!!

TestStart.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['TestId']))
    {
        $TestId = $_SESSION['TestId'];
    }
    include('Config.php');
    include('Reference.php');
    $query = "select * from testquestions where testid='".$TestId."'";
    $res = mysql_query($query);

    if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0)
    {
        $z = array();
        while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
            $z[]=$fetch['QId']; 
        }
        $y = implode(",", $z);

        $_SESSION['QIds']=$z;

    }
    else{

        echo mysql_error();
    }
?>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" id="resultDiv">
                <div class="col-md-12" id="qtext"></div>
                <div class="col-md-12">

                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input type="radio" id="optionA"name="options" value="A"><span id="optA"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input type="radio" id="optionB" name="options" Value="B"><span id="optB"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input type="radio" id="optionC" name="options" value="C"><span id="optC"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input type="radio" id="optionD" name="options" value="D"><span id="optD"></span> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="nextbuttondiv"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            <?php
                if(isset($_GET['qno'])&&isset($_GET['qindex']))
                {
                    $qno = $_GET['qno'];
                    $qindex = $_GET['qindex'];
                }
                else{
                    $qno = '1';
                    $qindex = '0';
                }

            ?>
            var qno = <?php echo $qno;?>;
            var qindex = <?php echo $qindex;?>;
            var qidsarrCm = '<?php echo $y;?>';
            var arrQid = qidsarrCm.split(",");

            var totalQuestions = arrQid.length;


            $.ajax({
                type : "post",
                url : "GetQuestionForTest.php",
                data : {
                    "quId" : arrQid[qindex]
                },
                dataType : "json",
                success : function(data){
                    alert('xy');
                    console.log(data);
                    $.each(data, function(){
                        var qText = this.questiontext;
                        var optionA = this.OptionA;
                        var optionB = this.OptionB;
                        var optionC = this.OptionC;
                        var optionD = this.OptionD;
                        var nxtBtn = this.NextButton;

                        $('#qtext').text(qText);
                        $('#optA').text(optionA);
                        $('#optB').text(optionB);
                        $('#optC').text(optionC);
                        $('#optD').text(optionD);
                        $('#nextbuttondiv').html(nxtBtn);
                    });
                },
                error: function(data, statusCode, xhr){
                    alert(statusCode);
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(xhr);
                }
            });
            $('input[type=radio]').on('click',function(){
                $('.nxtbtn').removeAttr('disabled');
            });



            $('body').on('click','.nxtbtn', function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type : "post",
                    url : "SaveTestAnswers.php",
                    data : {
                        "qid" : arrQid[qindex],
                        "ansId" : $('input[name=options]:checked').val(),
                        "stuId" : <?php echo $_SESSION['CurrentUser'];?>,
                        "testId" : <?php echo $TestId;?>
                    },  
                    dataType : "json",
                    success : function(data){

                        if(data.toString() == "true"){
                            qindex = qindex + 1;
                            qno = qno + 1;
                            if(qno > totalQuestions){
                                    window.location.href="TestFinish.php";
                            }
                                else{
                                        window.location.href="TestStart.php?qno="+qno+"&qindex="+qindex;
                                }

                        }
                        else{
                            alert(data + "Please resubmit the answer");
                        }
                    },
                    error : function(data, statusCode, xhr){
                    alert(statusCode);
                        console.log(data);
                        console.log(xhr);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

GetQuestionForTest.php

```
<?php
    $questionid = $_POST['quId'];
    include('Config.php');

    $query = "select * from questionstable where questionid = '".$questionid."'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        $someArray = [];
        while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            array_push($someArray,[
            'questiontext' => $fetch['questiontext'],
            'OptionA' => $fetch['optionA'],
            'OptionB' => $fetch['optionB'],
            'OptionC' => $fetch['optionC'],
            'OptionD' => $fetch['optionD'],
            'NextButton' => '<button  class="btn btn-success nxtbtn" disabled >Next</button>'
            ]);
        }
        $someJSON = json_encode($someArray);
        echo $someJSON; 
    }
    else{
        echo mysql_error();
    }
?>
```

SaveTestAnswers.php

```
<?php

    $qid = $_POST['qid'];
    $ansId = $_POST['ansId'];
    $stuId = $_POST['stuId'];
    $testId = $_POST['testId'];


    include('Config.php');
    $query = "insert into testattemptedanswers(StudentId,TestId,QuestionId,AnswerGiven) values('".$stuId."','".$testId."','".$qid."','".$ansId."')";
    $res = mysql_query($query);
    if($res){
        echo 'true';
    }
    else{
        echo 'false'.mysql_error();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Pls tell us the exact error u r getting. Posting code is not enough.

Comment: consider using mysqli or pdo

Comment: @Pushkar I have briefly explained it again. This might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Missing quotes -

```
var qno = <?php echo $qno;?>;
var qindex = <?php echo $qindex;?>;
```

Change them to -

```
var qno = '<?php echo $qno;?>';
var qindex = '<?php echo $qindex;?>';
```

And here also -

```
 data : {
     "qid" : arrQid[qindex],
     "ansId" : $('input[name=options]:checked').val(),
     "stuId" : '<?php echo $_SESSION['CurrentUser'];?>',
     "testId" : '<?php echo $TestId;?>'
 },
```

Comment: @sgtBose but values are getting posted to the php script without single quotes.

Comment: With ajax it is posted?

Comment: yes they are posted with ajax and also the values from php code are just numeric values.

Comment: No it is working fine with and without quotes as data is coming to php script. The quotes has no issue I guess.